# most frequent count of a column value when the values are comma separated

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to find the top most no of ratings watched by gender and age with ratings separated by comma in that particular column, I need to get the top most one with combination of gender and age.

Data:

```
gender  age rating 
M   young   pg13, r, nr
M   adult   r,pg13, pg
F   young   nr,r,pg13
M   adult   r,nr,pg13,ur
M   young   nr,r,pg13
F   adult   pg13,nr,r,ur
F   young   ur, nr, r, 
F   young   pg13
```

code :

```
gen = df.set_index(['gender', 'age']['rating'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
g= gen.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
```

output :

```
print(g)

gender  age
M     young         pg13
F     adult          nr
M     adult           r

print(gen)

gender  age
M       young   0          pg13
                1           nr
                2           r
                3          nr
 F  adult       0           r
                1           nr
                2             pg13
```

As the stack() function joins the column by ratings after splitting the rating values, the ratings here are not in order. Hence my output doesn't match.

Expected output :

```
M young  pg13
F adult  r
```

Comment: **1.** Your expected output is missing `F, young` and `M, adult`. Do you care about those as well? **2.** I don't get the same `g` as you list. Your code is missing `level=[0, 1]`, so I modified it to this and got sane-looking output: `g = gen.groupby(level=[0, 1]).apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])`. **3.** Note that your code tie-breaks by sorting ratings in lexicographic order. For example, `M, adult` has two counts each of `pg13` and `r`, and `pg13` sorts above `r`, so the result is `pg13`.

Comment: Thanks Peter, My output here doesnt match. Yes am looking into __F, young__ and __M, adult__ . The g here is wrong, please dont consider that .